# Troubleshooting Aruba 92 Access Point

Tags: wifi, access-point, aruba

We have an Aruba wireless system with five current access points and a virtual controller. I have just purchased another (Aruba 92) access point and can't get the controller to recognize it. The power LED is blinking green, the Enet LED is blinking amber. The access point is plugged into our HP PoE switch that the other ones are plugged into, but it is not getting an IP from the DHCP server.

The virtual controller version is 5.0.3

I am fairly new to Aruba and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say virtual controller, do you mean you are using IAP (Instant Access Point)? If thats the case, the AP 92 isnt capable of connecting to an IAP since its just a "dumb" AP.

Comment: That was it, thanks! They sent me an AP 92 instead of an IAP92!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say virtual controller, do you mean you are using IAP (Instant Access Point)? If thats the case, the AP 92 isnt capable of connecting to an IAP since its just a "dumb" AP.
The difference between IAP is that it has a two separate boot partitions. One is for IAP firmware since IAP has an entirely different type of infrastructure, compared to an traditional AP, and the other for traditional AP firmware.
Traditional AP's only have one boot partition and hence it cant recognize the IAP infrastructure.